# Problems with OpenGL driver

Tags: boot, screen

I am having problems using the experimental OpenGL driver on Pi2 and Pi3: The system boots up normally, then I will see about 10 seconds the login prompt on console. Then the screen goes blank. The system responds normally via SSH, but there are no errors, neither in dmesg, syslog or messages. When trying to start X, it outputs "no screens found". The Pi is connected to a 1080p monitor via HDMI. Has anyone had such issues? Is there a workaround?

dmesg:

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.1.18-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #846 SMP Thu Feb 25 14:22:53 GMT 2016
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd034] revision 4 (ARMv7), cr=10c5383d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 256 MiB at 0x20000000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 241664
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 80876f80, node_mem_map ba726000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 2124 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 241664 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] enter (9420->f3003010)
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] ncores=4
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 12 pages/cpu @ba6e7000 s20416 r8192 d20544 u49152
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s20416 r8192 d20544 u49152 alloc=12*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 239540
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 cma=256M@512M dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1824 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=984 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa02082 bcm2709.serial=0xb24d8176 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:4D:81:76 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.uart_clock=48000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 684964K/966656K available (6024K kernel code, 534K rwdata, 1660K rodata, 448K init, 757K bss, 19548K reserved, 262144K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xbb800000 - 0xff000000   (1080 MB)
    lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0xbb000000   ( 944 MB)
    modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
      .text : 0x80008000 - 0x807895a0   (7686 kB)
      .init : 0x8078a000 - 0x807fa000   ( 448 kB)
      .data : 0x807fa000 - 0x8087fac0   ( 535 kB)
       .bss : 0x80882000 - 0x8093f79c   ( 758 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Additional per-CPU info printed with stalls.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:608
[    0.000000] Architected cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x46d987e47, max_idle_ns: 440795202767 ns
[    0.000009] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 4398046511078ns
[    0.000027] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 52ns
[    0.000243] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001288] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.001341] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=192000)
[    0.001410] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.001727] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.001770] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.002764] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[    0.002812] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.002860] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.002903] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.002951] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.003021] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.003106] ftrace: allocating 20309 entries in 60 pages
[    0.048740] CPU0: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.048804] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.048837] [bcm2709_smp_prepare_cpus] enter
[    0.049000] Setting up static identity map for 0x8240 - 0x8274
[    0.050778] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:1 started (0) 18
[    0.051117] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:1
[    0.051161] CPU1: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.051167] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.051539] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:2 started (0) 17
[    0.051795] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:2
[    0.051816] CPU2: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.051822] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
[    0.052175] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:3 started (0) 17
[    0.052359] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:3
[    0.052380] CPU3: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.052386] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
[    0.052447] Brought up 4 CPUs
[    0.052544] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (153.60 BogoMIPS).
[    0.052574] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.052600] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.053293] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.071863] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 40 variant 3 rev 4
[    0.072133] clocksource jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.082922] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.083508] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.088727] DMA: preallocated 4096 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.089732] bcm2709.uart_clock = 48000000
[    0.095015] bcm2709: Mini UART enabled
[    0.095083] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.095130] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.095305] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.095456] 3f201000.uart: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 83, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    0.095916] bcm2835-mbox 3f00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.159562] bcm2708-dmaengine 3f007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at f3007000, dmachans=0xf35
[    0.159636] bcm2708-dmaengine 3f007000.dma: Initialized 7 DMA channels (+ 1 legacy)
[    0.160233] bcm2708-dmaengine 3f007000.dma: Load BCM2835 DMA engine driver
[    0.160270] bcm2708-dmaengine 3f007000.dma: dma_debug:0
[    0.160838] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.161048] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.161166] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.161284] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.161832] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2016-02-25 14:25
[    0.188948] Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.230465] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.230748] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.239928] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.240884] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.241026] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.241236] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.241351] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.241420] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.241744] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.242063] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.242095] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.242123] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.242150] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.243213] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.244304] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.257748] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.258039] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.260109] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    0.261043] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.261106] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.261134] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.263215] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    0.263387] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.263427] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.263718] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.265204] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.269059] console [ttyS0] disabled
[    0.269136] 3f215040.uart: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x3f215040 (irq = 29, base_baud = 62500000) is a 16550
[    1.731107] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    1.739131] vc-cma: Videocore CMA driver
[    1.747095] vc-cma: vc_cma_base      = 0x00000000
[    1.756670] vc-cma: vc_cma_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    1.767648] vc-cma: vc_cma_initial   = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    1.778773] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3dc00000 mem_size:0x3f000000(1008 MiB)
[    1.806792] brd: module loaded
[    1.819870] loop: module loaded
[    1.827835] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xa0400000, is_master = 0
[    1.843308] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    1.853882] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.865605] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    2.077596] Core Release: 2.80a
[    2.083992] Setting default values for core params
[    2.093758] Finished setting default values for core params
[    2.305414] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    2.312158] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    2.324013] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    2.335339] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    2.344199] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    2.351529] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1047: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = 0xa0448000 dma = 0xe0448000 len=9024
[    2.371536] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
Non-periodic Split Transactions
Periodic Split Transactions
High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
[    2.405489] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    2.405538] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:412: FIQ on core 1 at 0x8040ecc0
[    2.417562] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:413: FIQ ASM at 0x8040f030 length 36
[    2.430289] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:438: MPHI regs_base at 0xbb89c000
[    2.442508] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.452630] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.467523] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: irq 32, io mem 0x00000000
[    2.478892] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    2.486868] Init: Power Port (0)
[    2.493608] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    2.507415] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.522109] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.531676] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.1.18-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    2.543895] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
[    2.553956] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.561638] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    2.569989] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    2.569998] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    2.570006] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    2.570037] Module dwc_common_port init
[    2.570289] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.582675] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.594689] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=600000 max=1000000
[    2.604888] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.617454] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.626608] sdhost: log_buf @ a0446000 (e0446000)
[    2.708981] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    2.742554] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    2.754417] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: DMA channels allocated
[    2.769032] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    2.799055] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.810913] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.823248] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.834331] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    2.834410] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.834412] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.835694] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    2.835718] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.835830] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.836278] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    2.836912] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.837088] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    2.837097] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    2.850880] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    2.942474] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p7...
[    2.947299] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[    2.958982] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    2.959146] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    2.959182] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL32G 28.8 GiB 
[    3.003225]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 < p5 p6 p7 >
[    3.107496] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    3.122383] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    3.159238] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
[    3.172871] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.188055] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.195771] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    3.443461] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): recovery complete
[    3.465085] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.478986] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    3.495020] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:7.
[    3.525983] devtmpfs: mounted
[    3.532717] Freeing unused kernel memory: 448K (8078a000 - 807fa000)
[    3.579269] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    3.593262] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.610793] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[    3.672012] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:4d:81:76
[    3.788993] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.939951] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046a, idProduct=0801
[    3.953952] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.968828] usb 1-1.3: Product: Wired Keyboard
[    3.968835] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: NOVATEK
[    3.987174] input: NOVATEK Wired Keyboard as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:046A:0801.0001/input/input0
[    4.034558] random: systemd urandom read with 62 bits of entropy available
[    4.052277] systemd[1]: systemd 215 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR)
[    4.069239] hid-generic 0003:046A:0801.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [NOVATEK Wired Keyboard] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.3/input0
[    4.099638] input: NOVATEK Wired Keyboard as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/0003:046A:0801.0002/input/input1
[    4.130152] systemd[1]: Detected architecture 'arm'.
[    4.159374] hid-generic 0003:046A:0801.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [NOVATEK Wired Keyboard] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.3/input1
[    4.340866] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    4.351263] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'ipv6'
[    4.364840] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    4.837997] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-ttyS0.device...
[    4.850143] systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    4.866002] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    4.881509] systemd[1]: Starting Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    4.893111] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    4.905680] systemd[1]: Starting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    4.924002] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    4.943215] systemd[1]: Starting Encrypted Volumes.
[    4.953391] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    4.964487] systemd[1]: Starting Swap.
[    4.972364] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    4.981144] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-mmcblk0p6.device...
[    4.993594] systemd[1]: Starting Root Slice.
[    5.002604] systemd[1]: Created slice Root Slice.
[    5.012265] systemd[1]: Starting User and Session Slice.
[    5.023483] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    5.035263] systemd[1]: Starting /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    5.049144] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    5.063387] systemd[1]: Starting Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    5.074707] systemd[1]: Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    5.086484] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    5.098190] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    5.110341] systemd[1]: Starting udev Control Socket.
[    5.120964] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    5.132058] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Socket.
[    5.142456] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    5.153376] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
[    5.163138] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    5.173403] systemd[1]: Starting System Slice.
[    5.182856] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    5.192917] systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on Root Device...
[    5.208338] systemd[1]: Starting system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    5.221098] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    5.234115] systemd[1]: Starting system-autologin.slice.
[    5.245628] systemd[1]: Created slice system-autologin.slice.
[    5.257460] systemd[1]: Starting system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    5.270051] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    5.283036] systemd[1]: Starting Increase datagram queue length...
[    5.298226] systemd[1]: Starting Restore / save the current clock...
[    5.321453] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    5.343247] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    5.357783] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    5.418049] systemd[1]: Started Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
[    5.497688] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    5.511396] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    5.523211] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    5.536073] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
[    5.544688] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    5.555998] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[    5.566565] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    5.577331] fuse init (API version 7.23)
[    5.591573] systemd[1]: Started Increase datagram queue length.
[    5.604108] i2c /dev entries driver
[    5.624932] systemd[1]: Started Restore / save the current clock.
[    5.638574] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    5.661032] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[    5.683420] systemd[1]: Time has been changed
[    5.711761] systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[    5.827220] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[    5.841844] systemd[1]: Mounting Configuration File System...
[    5.856102] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    5.870641] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[    5.886700] systemd[1]: Starting Syslog Socket.
[    5.896389] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    5.906457] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    5.920042] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    6.437764] systemd-udevd[109]: starting version 215
[    7.583330] bcm2708_i2c 3f805000.i2c: BSC2 Controller at 0x3f805000 (irq 79) (baudrate 100000)
[    7.953818] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    8.587918] bcm2835-rng 3f104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    8.588614] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x3f200000
[    8.590776] vc4-drm soc:gpu@7e4c0000: bound 3f902000.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops [vc4])
[    8.590902] vc4-drm soc:gpu@7e4c0000: bound 3f807000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[    8.591005] vc4-drm soc:gpu@7e4c0000: bound 3f207000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[    8.591093] vc4-drm soc:gpu@7e4c0000: bound 3f206000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[    8.591156] vc4-drm soc:gpu@7e4c0000: bound 3f400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
[    8.591446] vc4-drm soc:gpu@7e4c0000: bound 3fc00000.v3d (ops vc4_v3d_ops [vc4])
[    8.592541] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    8.592557] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[    8.668166] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    8.711730] vc4-drm soc:gpu@7e4c0000: fb0:  frame buffer device
[    8.711759] vc4-drm soc:gpu@7e4c0000: registered panic notifier
[    9.893398] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   19.753072] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   20.001184] systemd-journald[106]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   21.205935] uart-pl011 3f201000.uart: no DMA platform data
[   21.309860] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   21.503138] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:2 across:110588k SSFS
[   21.570727] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   21.570749] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   21.570754] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   21.570763] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   21.570771] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   21.570779] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   21.570791] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   21.570801] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   21.570808] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   21.570816] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   21.570823] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[   22.020294] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   22.020463] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   23.535510] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   23.536470] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC5E1
[   25.616966] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   25.617058] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   25.617069] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   25.617094] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   25.617113] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   25.617148] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   25.625284] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   25.625309] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   25.625320] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   25.625329] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[   25.762050] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   25.762053] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   25.762070] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Very same issue here must be something to do with new version of jessie.

Comment: Tried to compile a newer kernel directly from the repo today. Raspberry boots fine but OpenGL is kind of broken

Comment: The delay-and-then-screen-goes-black made me think that you were missing avoid_warnings=2 in config.txt.  I'm not sure what would be up with X, though. You'd need to post the Xorg.0.log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem must be related to the `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d`. Whenever this Device Tree overlay is activated, Pi doesn't support console output anymore. However you can operate as before. You can even type username and password to login on any tty. Which you can confirm that you logged in and have a running shell by using `w` command. You can still start X on :0, then `export DISPLAY=:0` variable and finanly by using `xcompmgr -a` to have hardware accelerated OpenGL support on that X screen.

It is related to DT overlay, because in usage of vc4 the simple frame buffer in startup gets disabled as i understand. That is why no kernel outputs are seen on startup. After vc4 taken place, system is failing to use vc4 for virtual console.

There are related firmware issues [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/595) and [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/597).

Comment: That's a misinterpretation of those bug reports.  Console output is supported (works fine for me, and for the folks at the Pi Foundation who've merged my code), but something has gone wrong for this specific user.